# Does hash_map automatically sort [C++]?

Tags: c++, hashmap

In the below code, hash_map is automatically sorting or maybe inserting elements in a sorted order. Any ideas why it does this?? Suggestions Please??
This is NOT a homework problem, trying to solve an interview question posted on glassdoor dot com.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ext/hash_map>
#include <map>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace __gnu_cxx;
using namespace std;

struct eqstr
{
  bool operator()(int i, int j) const
  {
    return i==j;
  }
};
typedef hash_map<int, int, hash<int>, eqstr> myHash;
int main()
{
    myHash array;
    int inputArr[20] = {1,43,4,5,6,17,12,163,15,16,7,18,19,20,122,124,125,126,128,100};

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        array[inputArr[i]] = inputArr[i]; //save value
    }
    myHash::iterator it = array.begin();
    int data;
    for (; it != array.end(); ++it) {
        data =  it->first;
        cout << ":: " << data;
    }
}

//!Output ::: 1:: 4:: 5:: 6:: 7:: 12:: 15:: 16:: 17:: 18:: 19:: 20:: 43:: 100:: 122:: 124:: 125:: 126:: 128:: 163
```

Comment: Any reason that the `operator()` is not implemented as `return i == j;`?

Comment: `hash_map` is not standard C++.  The C++0x equivalent is `unordered_map`.  This means that there are no standard C++ requirements, and it's entirely up to the implementation.  So...what platform are you using, and what implementation of `hash_map`?

Comment: ubuntu 10.04 , stl implementation. Thanks David

Comment: hey Arun.. not any specific reason. i just used same code from STL::hash_map implementation .. so didn't care to change anything.

Comment: Thanks Arun.. my bad.. I wasn't paying attention to what I was doing there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hash map will not automatically *sort* your data. In fact the order is unspecified, depending on your hash function and input order. It is just that  in your case the numbers turns out are sorted.

You may want to read about [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for how this container stores the data.

A clear counter example can be created by replacing that 100 with 999999999. The result is

```
:: 1:: 4:: 5:: 6:: 7:: 12:: 15:: 16:: 17:: 18:: 19:: 20:: 999999999:: 43:: 122:: 124:: 125:: 126:: 128:: 163
```

---

(The actual reason is the hash_map's `bucket_count` is 193 and the hash function of `int` is an identity function, so any numbers below 193 will appear sorted.)

Comment: Thanks kenny. exactly what I was trying to understand. :D

Comment: Do you know if there's a way i can insert random unsorted numbers into a hash and retrieve them in sorted order with a complexity O(n)?

Comment: @reddy: Use counting sort or radix sort.

Answer (score 1):

A hash map may *appear* to be sorted based on a few factors:

- The hash function returns values that are in the same order as the input, for the range of input that you are providing.
- There are no hash collisions.

There are no guarantees that the results will be sorted, it's only a coincidence if they come out that way.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how the hash function operates.  A hash is always a function *f:input->output* that maps the input set I into a (usually smaller) output set O so that the input set is approximately uniformly distributed across the output set.

There is no *requirement* that order should be preserved; in fact, it's unusual that it would be preserved, because (since the output set is smaller) there will be values *i,j*that have the same hash.  This is called a *collision*.

On the other hand, there's no reason it shouldn't.  IN fact, it can be proven that there will always exist at least one sequence that *will* preserve the order.

But there's another possibility: if ALL the values collide, then they get stored in some other kind of data structure, like a list.  It may be that these all collidge, and the other structure imposes order.

Three possibilities: `hash_map` happens to sort that particular sequence, or `hash_map` is actually implimented as an array, or the values collidge and the implementation stores collisions in a way that gives a sorted order.